# What is the performance impact of Solr's debug=results?

Tags: performance, solr, lucene

Solr queries support a parameter [debug=results](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/common-query-parameters.html#debug-parameter) that explains the relevance of each returned document.

I'm currently considering to activate this for all our queries in a production environment to simplify handling of support requests about unexpected search results. I understand that this slightly increases the network load but could not find any mention if it also degrades performance in any noticable way.

My guess would be that all the information provided has to be collected at some point anyway so the performance impact should be neglible. There's a few CPU cycles to be expected to build the JSON strings with the debug information for the query result, but that's about it.

So both the impact on network load and performance would be within a single digit percent range.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Test it. It'll have to build a few more strings and keep track of slightly more information during the request, but exactly how much will depend on your query.

Comment: if this is prod, and handling substantial load, you will notice a big difference, I did at least when I enabled in prod environment